# Identify palindromes in a sentence

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, palindrome

A lot of solutions I found here are giving true or false after checking if a string is a palindrome. I have a function that checks if a string is a palindrome or not:

```
    function palindrome(myString){

    /* remove special characters, spaces and make lowercase*/
    var removeChar = myString.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "").toLowerCase();

    /* reverse removeChar for comparison*/
    var checkPalindrome = removeChar.split('').reverse().join('');

    /* Check to see if myString is a Palindrome*/
    if(removeChar === checkPalindrome){

    document.write("<div>"+ myString + " is a Palindrome <div>");
    }else{

    document.write("<div>" + myString + " is not a Palindrome </div>");
    }
    }

    palindrome("Oh who was it I saw, oh who?")
    palindrome("Madam")
    palindrome("Star Wars")
```

But this is not quite what I want. It's just checking if the string is a palindrome or not. I want to update the function so that it **identifies all of the palindromes in a sentence** instead of giving it true or false. So if there's a sentence like this - "Madam and John went out at noon" It will list the palindromes in that sentence - "Madam, noon"

Any help in this would be appreciated!

Comment: Why the triple quotation? `palindrome('"Oh who was it I saw, oh who?"')`

Comment: @SergioAlen that was just to show "" in my work.

Comment: This seems very open ended. What are the restrictions? For instance, I can see more palindromes in that *"Madam and John..."* sentence, eg "Madam", "am a", "t at", "noon" and "oo"

Comment: @Phil I guess interview questions are open-ended. I was just trying this interview question I found on the internet : "On the whiteboard, write a program that identifies all of the palindromes in a sentence."

Comment: First question I'd ask is *"what is the minimum string length to qualify as a palindrome?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function findPalindromes(str, min) {
  min = min || 3;
  var result = [];
  var reg = str.toLowerCase();
  var reg = reg.replace(/[^a-z]/g, ''); // remove if you want spaces
  var rev = reg.split("").reverse().join("");
  var l = reg.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
    for (var j = i + min; j <= l; j++) {
      var regs = reg.substring(i, j);
      var revs = rev.substring(l - j, l - i);
      if (regs == revs) {
        result.push(regs);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var str1 = "Madam and John went out at noon";
console.log(str1, findPalindromes(str1));
var str2 = "\"Amore, Roma\" and \"There's no 'x' in Nixon\" are palindromes.";
console.log(str2, findPalindromes(str2));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I was wondering if you could explain this snippet " min = min || 3; "  Is this checking the minimum length? I know || it is an "OR" operator

Comment: || is the OR operator but in JS it's also the null coalescing operator.  So if you assign something like that `min = min || 3`, then min will be set to its original value if that value evaluates truthy (e.g. if it's not null), and will be set to 3 if it's falsy (e.g. false or null values).

Answer (score -1):

```
function findPalindromes(sentence) {
  const words = sentence.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '').split(' ');
  const palindromes = words.filter(isPalindrome);
  return palindromes;
}

function isPalindrome(word) {
  if (word.length <= 0) return false;
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  for (let i = 0; i < word.length / 2; i++) {
    if (word[i] !== word[word.length - 1 - i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ewezbz22/1/

Comment: The general idea behind palindromes is to ignore punctuation and space

Comment: @Phil Thank you for the feedback. I've updated my answer to handle special characters.